# Background Task in Windows phone is not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, background

I am Working on Background task in Windows phone application but it is not calling .When do launch for test it is working but in real scenario app is not calling background services.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use [ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)? This function is not supposed to work on a real phone. You have to deal with the fact that instead of running every 1-2 minutes your background task will be launched once every 30 minutes or so as stated in [Constraints For Periodic Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) section.

If everything is fine in your simulator, you have to cross your fingers and keep waiting for a half of hour or so just to test that you are actually launched. Yes, it's a pain to debug, but we have no other official way.

You may also try adjusting local time on device. Sometimes going half an hour into the future helps trigger background agent immediately.